# ¿Cómo pudo rechazar una sugerencia de edición alguien sin reputación para hacerlo?

Tags: soporte, ediciones-sugeridas

Últimamente he estado participando más en esta comunidad. Cuando no encuentro preguntas que puedo responder, lo que hago es ver otras preguntas, tanto para aprender cosas nuevas como para ver si enriquecen la comunidad.

De igual manera he empezado a editar preguntas, sobre todo cuando se trata de bloques de código (que muchas veces copian y pegan y no se preocupan de que se pueda leer).

Hoy hice una edición de una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96382/actualizar-un-valor-mediante-una-condici%C3%B3n) que contenia un bloque de código en PHP pero que estaba mal formateado. Para mi sorpresa, la edición fue rechazada.

A continuación el [enlace a la revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/60086).

Mi sorpresa fue que la persona que rechazó mi edición además de que no tiene reputación [aprobó una edición anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/60083) en la que la persona que la realizó fue quien desacomodó el formato del bloque de código.

¿Cómo fue que esta persona (sin reputación y según su perfil con poca participación en la comunidad) apruebe o rechace ediciones sugeridas de esa manera?

Comment: Espero que tus sugerencias de edición no involucren tildes, porque no has puesto ninguna :P

Comment: Jajaja, desventajas de teclado en ingles...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fácil, porque es el autor de la pregunta

Comment: Ok, no habia visto eso, ni sabia que se podia...